# How to contribute to FontAwesome? SVG, EPS to fontawesome?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, eps, svg

I am very interested in contributing to `fontawesome`. I have some vector icons that I feel the community would benefit to use and I really like to add them to `fontawesome`. These icons are in svg and eps format. Could someone tell me if it is possible to convert them to fonts compatible with `fontawesome`? What are the things that one needs to consider to design a font for `fontawesome`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I voted to close as off topic. Here you can find what you want: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/community/